# Project wise dependencies in a multi module project maven

Tags: maven

In a multi module project, lets say we have 3 modules A, B, C. Now project C is dependent on project A and B. I have created a mojo where i need to list all the dependencies including the transitive ones.

So i have injected the project via @Parameter annotation and calling the getArtifacts method gives all the dependencies combined from project A and B. Is there any way i can list all the transitive dependencies separate for each project.

Comment: What is the purpose of your plugin what you like to create?

Comment: i am working on a gigaspace based project, i am creating a module seperate for integration testing and i need to deploy jars one by one. So that i can run my tests against deployed application. So first i need to deploy module A, then module B. Hence i need seperate list of dependencies for each of them